# Is it possible in Java to find out the generic type of a collection getter via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class with a collection getter that I'm inspecting via reflection. Something like this:

```
class Bar {
  String baz;
  int bazooka;
}
class Foo {
  List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();
  List<Bar> getBarsList() { return bars; }
}
```

What I need to find out at runtime is the class object `Class<Bar>`. I know it's possible if you have a reference to the `Field` object. But is it also possible from the getter `Method`?

Comment: Do you want to know what the type of the list is in the getBarsList method? Also, shouldn't the class itself have a generic parameter Bar? Btw there is a way (more or less), but you need to answer those questions first.

Comment: @Bohemian I want to get the class object of `Bar`. I edited the example above for clarity, class `Foo` does not have a generic parameter `Bar`, but `Bar` is a concrete class itself.

Comment: The answer differs depending on if the class is parameterized or not, hence the differing answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case it is possible using reflection. What you can't do is get runtime information about types. Given an instance of a parametrized type, you can't at runtime find out what that was parametrized with. This is what the other answers are telling you, but that's not what you're asking. You're asking about compile time type constraints.

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    Method method = Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("getBars", new Class[]{});
    Type grt = method.getGenericReturnType();
    if (grt instanceof ParameterizedType) {
      Type Bar = ((ParameterizedType) grt).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
      System.out.println(Bar);
    }
  }
}

class Foo {
  List<Bar> getBars() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
}

class Bar {
}
```

Prints `class com.package.Bar`

If on the other hand you had a class like this:

```
class Foo<T> {
  List<T> getBars() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
}
```

Then you could not get T for instances of Foo at runtime. There exists workarounds, where people create anonymous subclasses with the type parameter fixed.

Answer (score 1):

That information is not present at run-time, due to two reasons:

1) It's not needed there. That's a hint to the compiler, and to conform with your strong typing methods.

2) Java uses generic types erasure to keep compatibility with the pre-generic types.

You **can** however do it in a alternate way (dumb, but will work, if the code is yours):

```
class MyGenericClass extends ArrayList<MyObject> {

     // Check the class for this variable name. Its type will indicate the generic type.
     // Alternatively we can use the type class instance directly.
     final static MyObject mGenericType      = null; 
     final static Class    mGenericTypeClass = MyObject.getClass();

}
```

I understand that's a partial solution (if any solution at all), but still, better than nothing if you **really** need this.

On a second thought, there is an easy way to do this. You could make a retainable annotation with an argument which will provide information on the generic type of the annotated class/field.

Comment: I like your idea of using an annotation. Will have a look into that.

Comment: I'd rather just store the actual Class instance then rather than an object instance, but +1 for a creative thinking outside of the box solution that will always work.